# Dark/Light mode using two CSS files

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a web software, that allows to create themes. It creates a single CSS file per theme, so i've got two CSS files: dark.css and light.css.

What's the best way to create a dark/light mode **switch** (independent from the visitor's system settings) using both CSS files? I've tried loading the opposite theme upon click, but that's very impractical and requires at least one more roundtrip.

I can embed the CSS files contents into the DOM, if that helps to achieve a smooth switch.

Comment: Loading both files at once is of no concern unless you have 1990s internet speed available. Loading and unloading the correct CSS file will make more problems than it solves. Alternate solution: Add a class to the body like `light` and `dark` which the CSS uses. Then you can just switch the body class to make it independant of `prefers-color-scheme`.

Answer (score 10):

If you'd like to keep CSS files separate you can use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="css/light.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"
    href="css/dark.css">
```

Answer (score 8):

The most simple solution I can think of is to just include both files and use media queries:

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

The browser will then use the user's system colour scheme to determine which set of CSS to use.

(For the sake of legacy browsers, it's probably best to only have one of the files have the media query and include that file second)

Comment: Well, thank you for that. However, I am looking for a solution that works independent from the system's settings. The visitor should be able to switch between those two schemes, without changing any system settings. So I'm searching for a "normal" dark/light mode switch with the difficulty of working with two separate CSS files (which I could embed into the website for easier access).